# Create web_sys::RtcPeerConnection with customized configuration

Tags: rust, webrtc, webassembly, web-sys

I am trying to figure how to create a [`RtcPeerConnection`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.31/web_sys/struct.RtcPeerConnection.html) with the `web-sys` crate. In JavaScript I can write the following:

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({'iceServers': [{'urls': ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302']}]});
```

How does this translate to rust? I have tried the following:

```
let mut rtc = RtcConfiguration::new();
let config = RtcConfiguration::ice_servers(&mut rtc, &JsValue::from_serde(&json!({"iceServers": [{"urls": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]})).unwrap());
let pc = RtcPeerConnection::new_with_configuration(&config).unwrap();
```

But it fails when creating `pc`. The `json!` macro is from `serde_json::json`.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @battlmonstr The error occurs when running the compiled webassembly in a browser. There is no readable error message and don't understand the webassembly language good enough to trace it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue, the following works:

```
let mut rtc = RtcConfiguration::new();
let config = rtc.ice_servers(&JsValue::from_serde(&json!([{"urls": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}])).unwrap());
let pc = RtcPeerConnection::new_with_configuration(&config).unwrap();
```